# Chrome and div background layers not loading properly

Tags: html, google-chrome

This is a very weird thing that i've experienced . I've been working on a project lately www.bandness.com, which allows music groups and bands to upload their music. The artistic department has been very keen and precise and they've done an incredible work that allows the bands to have gorgeous profiles .

However, when on Chrome (i've noticed this only happens in chrome), when you enter a profile the background image doesn't load properly until you scroll over it or you "select" the div layer or the ones on top of it.

here are some examples of what i'm talking about[image: The website loaded at first, notice the background how it's "broken"]
you need to select the layer so it works properly, and that is bugging annoying!!
[image: you have to select the layer so it works properly]

here you have another example[image: there ya go!]
[image: another example]

and this is how the website should be seen without the bug in the left screen
[image: what I want]

Why does this happen?

The website is www.bandness.com, click on any of the groups where it says "TOP 5 GROUPS" or on the group for each song in "TOP 5 SONGS" and you'll probably spot what I'm talking about.

This has happened to me in chrome, on a macbook pro with the latest OS release. As well as in Windows 8. It bugs me because I have NO idea what is causing this and I fear a chrome bug.

How could it be fixed? Any suggestions are appreciated, I thought of using `jQuery` to make the layer dissappear/appear or something like that... but i'm unsure of whether this will work.

Comment: Please refrain from language and use standard English writing conventions. Even if it's your second language, capitalizing the first letter of a sentence is a pretty universal European languages rule that makes it easier to read your posts.

Comment: these are the comments that make me realise about .... http://www.lowbird.com/data/images/2013/04/explosm-itsnotitsnew.gif

Comment: Please refrain from commenting about the lack of a few capital letters and completely ignoring the real problem. If I wanted a grammar check I would have asked for it. Anyway thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm talking mainly about your repeated use of the f-word but also the effort you put into your post.

Comment: that's cos of the frustration that this issue produces me :-(, not knowing nor understanding makes me want to say the f-word...

Comment: and besides... my post was ok! i put images so people can know what i'm talking about. I'm sure that for someone that knows about this it must be like reading a children's book!!! :-D

Comment: So did you try `$(SELECTOR).hide().show()` just to see if it worked? That'll give you something to start w/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm posting this as a help for anyone that suffers the same consequences of this bug at any time.Bear in mind the answer implies using jQuery.

As Christopher kindly pointed out earlier, I tried to do $(SELECTOR).hide().show(), but that didn't make it.
Then I decided to try with $(SELECTOR).hide(100,function(){$(SELECTOR).show()}); ensuring that the effect of showing only happens once the div layer has dissapeared.(that way it actually appears and dissappears).

The solution worked, however this should not be needed and it doesn't provide an answer to why this is happening, but it "kinda" makes the trick .

$(SELECTOR).fadeOut(100,function(){ $(SELECTOR).fadeIn()}); makes this happen in a much fancier way. Again as I said this isn't a fix, it's just a workaround that might get you somewhere if you ever suffer this problem!